# Is it possible to use the same layers in multiple files?

Tags: gimp, layers, automation

I am using Gimp 2 and I have over 50 pictures to edit. I have already edited one picture and I would like to use the same layers on every pic. Is there a way to automatically layer each pic in one click with those layers?

Answer (score 1):

If you further edit the image, `File>Open as layers` will import all layers from another image in one shot, so you can make an image with only those layers you want to import.

If it just to apply these layers to all images, you can produce a PNG with transparency from these layers and then use ImageMagick's compose to overlay your images with that logo/watermark...